# After use cwac-cam2 library, I can't install my app from Play Store in Nexux 7

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I have added the cwac-cam2 library to my project and I uploaded it in the play store. All seems to be good, but when I look my app in the play store from a nexus 7, the app says that isn't compatible with my device. Have you ever had a similar issue? I've read that could be the android permissions, but I didn't add new permissions. This is my AndroidManifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.waiter.android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.commonsware.cwac.cam2, com.github.clans.fab" />
<application
    android:name="com.waiter.android.WaiterApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
        android:value="waiter.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
        android:value="3" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.waiter.android.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.waiter.android.CommentsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.waiter.android.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.cam2.CameraActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:process=":cwac_cam2"/>

    <!-- Google Tag Manager Preview Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.tagmanager.PreviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" > <!-- Optional, removes the PreviewActivity from activity stack. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="tagmanager.c.com.waiter.android" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" />

    <!--Facebook login Activity-->
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>

</application>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if `tools:overrideLibrary` accepts a comma-delimited list, let alone one with a space in it. I'd start there.

Comment: if I let alone with a space, the project doesn't compile. In the documentation, says that you can use comma-delimited. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-tools:overrideLibrary-marker

Comment: You might want to look at your merged manifest (in your `build/` directory of your app module) to see what is in there that might be blocking the Nexus 7. Also, which Nexus 7 is this (2012? 2013?).